# how to add a download button in facebook App Page

Tags: android, facebook, native

I have developed an android app and integrated facebook to it. I want to add a button (like "Download") in facebook app page. I have seen for other app that they have added a download button and when we click on it, it launches Appstore link for that App. In the same manner I want to add a (custom)button to facebook page. When user clicks it should launch Android Market URL. I tried changing the app settings but couldn't find any.
Please help me acheive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide few details how you did it? So I can up vote to your answer & question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Simple link like this should do the job.

```
<a href="market://details?id=your.package.name.here">App Link</a>
```

If you want to be able to open the application's market page in a browser instead of the market app, use a link like this.

```
<a href="http://market.android.com/details?id=your.package.name.here">App Link</a>
```

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.please let me know where should I include this in facebook app settings page to get a button?

Comment: Sadly I'm not really familiar with the Facebook platform. I guess you need to put the link on the canvas page you put in settings or in the app page's description. It all depends on where and how you want the button to show.

Comment: @RCE Can you please provide some details of how to do above stuffs? So that I can up vote your answer